# What should I do if I assign an anchor/pivot point to an object, and the TransformControls are not updated synchronously?

Tags: three.js

[image]

What should I do if I assign an anchor/pivot point to an object, and the TransformControls are not updated synchronously?
**this is demo**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/three-ez-transformcontrols-1h48ro?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)